# Autocomplete in django and allow creating user if not found

Tags: django, autocomplete, django-autocomplete-light

I'm trying to add a search box for users on the webpage to see his profile, and if the user doesn't exist, then I have the option to create it.

In flask, I used a solution that used jquery for the autocomplete, and when no one was found, it would simply put "Create_user" as the text submitted in the form, and then redirect to the url for user creation.  I was not able to port this to django(javascript is not my forté and I'm starting django.)

So I tried django-autocomplete-light, but while the autocomplete worked, I found no way to replicate the behavior that would redirect me to the user creation page in the case no one was found. (the create exemple in the docs only allow to create a simple entry, while I need to create a user based on a model)

Any leads on how to accomplish this with django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what i was looking few days ago, i found this

**Example Admin code for autocomplete**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

from selectable.forms import AutoCompleteSelectField, AutoCompleteSelectMultipleWidget

from .models import Fruit, Farm
from .lookups import FruitLookup, OwnerLookup


class FarmAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    owner = AutoCompleteSelectField(lookup_class=OwnerLookup, allow_new=True)

    class Meta(object):
        model = Farm
        widgets = {
            'fruit': AutoCompleteSelectMultipleWidget(lookup_class=FruitLookup),
        }
        exclude = ('owner', )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FarmAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance and self.instance.pk and self.instance.owner:
            self.initial['owner'] = self.instance.owner.pk

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        owner = self.cleaned_data['owner']
        if owner and not owner.pk:
            owner = User.objects.create_user(username=owner.username, email='')
        self.instance.owner = owner
        return super(FarmAdminForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class FarmAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = FarmAdminForm


admin.site.register(Farm, FarmAdmin)
```

## Source code

https://github.com/mlavin/django-selectable

and

## Documentation

http://django-selectable.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Hope this will help you too

Comment: Thanks, I was able to make it work nicely with that one!